# How to send parameter to controller

Tags: magento2, controllers, parameter

I found this code below at `AddressesPost.php` for `addresses.phtml`. How can `addresses.phtml` send parameter `continue` or `new_address` so `AddressesPost.php` can `getParam('continue')` or `getParam('new_address')`?

**AddressesPost.php :**

```
if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('continue', false)) {
   $this->_getCheckout()->setCollectRatesFlag(true);
   $this->_getState()->setActiveStep(State::STEP_SHIPPING);
   $this->_getState()->setCompleteStep(State::STEP_SELECT_ADDRESSES);
   $this->_redirect('*/*/shipping');
} elseif ($this->getRequest()->getParam('new_address')) {
   $this->_redirect('*/checkout_address/newShipping');
} else {
   $this->_redirect('*/*/addresses');
}
```

I already add `<input type="hidden" name="split" value="0" id="split_flag"/>` and `<input type="hidden" name="update" value="0" id="update_flag"/>` in `addresses.phtml` and the getParam in controller like in code below.

**Controller :**

```
elseif ($this->getRequest()->getParam('new_address')) {
    $this->_redirect('*/checkout_address/newShipping');
} elseif ($this->getRequest()->getParam('split')) {
    $btn = $this->getRequest()->getPost('btn');
       if($post = $this->getRequest()->getPost('split')){
            $this->_getCheckout()->setSplitItemInformation($post, $btn);
       } else{
            $this->_redirect('*/*/addresses');
       }
} elseif ($this->getRequest()->getParam('update')) {
    $this->messageManager->addError('test');
    $this->_redirect('*/*/addresses');
} else {
    $this->_redirect('*/*/addresses');
}
```

It's work for getParam('split'), but it's not work for getParam('update').

Comment: It is default things, the fields access from controller when form is submitted.

Comment: So, how can i add new parameter so i could getParam('custom') in the controller?

Comment: You need to specify that field in your form which is submitted in controller.

Comment: which field did you mean?

Comment: In your form, you need to pass field with name "custom" so you get that field value in controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add one more field in the form itself. If you look into the template file below, you can see there is a hidden field called **continue**.

> {magento-root}/vendor/magento/module-multishipping/view/frontend/templates/checkout/addresses.phtml

Similar to this hidden field, you can also include your own custom field let say **your_custom_field** in this form.

```
<form id="checkout_multishipping_form" data-mage-init='{"multiShipping":{}, "validation":{}}' action="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" class="multicheckout address form">
    <div class="title">
        <strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Please select a shipping address for applicable items.') ?></strong>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="continue" value="0" id="can_continue_flag"/>

    .
    .
    .

    <input type="hidden" name="your_custom_field" value="0" id="your_custom_field"/>
</form>
```

Comment: already tried this, but it's not work.

Comment: Can you update your question with your code because just checked with this code `$this->getRequest()->getParam('your_custom_field')` in controller and it's working..

Comment: Could you check it again in my update?

Comment: Now i know the problem, the `<input type="hidden" name="your_custom_field" value="0" id="your_custom_field"/>` work fine, in my case, it's not work because i add 2 new input, and it's always checked on the first custom input, now i could solve the problem, thank you for the answer!!