# Pass parameter to controller from template Magento 2

Tags: magento2, controllers, data, parameter, custom-template

I am creating product programmatically on controller action. I want to send price value from template file. This is my controller:

```
public function execute()
{
    if (!$this->session->isLoggedIn())
    {
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $resultRedirect->setPath('customer/account/login');
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
    else
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('My Wallet'));
        return $resultPage;

        $vat_exempt_name = $this->getRequest()->getPost('vat_exempt_name');

    //.............To Create Product...........//

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // instance of object manager
        $product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
        $product->setSku('my-sku28'); // Set your sku here
        $product->setName('Sample Simple Product28'); // Name of Product
        $product->setAttributeSetId(4); // Attribute set id
        $product->setStatus(1); // Status on product enabled/ disabled 1/0
        $product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
        $product->setWeight(10); // weight of product
        $product->setVisibility(4); // visibilty of product (catalog / search / catalog, search / Not visible individually)
        $product->setTaxClassId(0); // Tax class id
        $product->setTypeId('simple'); // type of product (simple/virtual/downloadable/configurable)
        $product->setPrice($vat_exempt_name); // price of product
        $product->setStockData(
                 array(
                      'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
                      'manage_stock' => 1,
                      'is_in_stock' => 1,
                      'qty' => 99999
                      )
                     );
        $product = $product->save();
    }
}
```

This is my template file:

```
<table>
  <tr>
<th>Enter Amount to be Added in wallet (USD)</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><input type="text" class="input-text watch-keyup" id="vat_exempt_name" name="vat_exempt_name" value="200"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><button type="button">Add Money to Wallet</button></td>
 </tr>
```

How can I achieve it, Thanks.

Comment: you are so supposed to put it on a form

Comment: Is it an ajax request? However you gotta to send the data via post request to pass data to controller

Comment: Yes.. I looking for some example to achieve it..

Comment: check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/202692/how-to-send-parameter-to-controller?answertab=active#tab-top and this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149781/receive-post-parameters-in-magento-2-controller?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: What you mean by ` send price value from template file` .From  where you send from  and where to?

Comment: I am creating eWallet, for that will get account balance as price value from customer and save it creating product programmatically..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send values from phtml file to controller use form in phtml file with controller action

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('path/tothe/controller') ?>" method="post">
     <input type="text" class="input-text watch-keyup" id="vat_exempt_name" name="vat_exempt_name" value="200">
      <button type="submit">Add Money to Wallet</button>
</form>
```

And you can get this value in your controller below

```
public function execute()
{
  $posted = $this->getRequest()->getParam('vat_exempt_name');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for simple solution.

Comment: Welcome...:-)..